# How can Decode Json data in relational table laravel 5.8

Tags: json, laravel, parsing, laravel-blade

I have a table `Pemeliharaan` with a column `pertanyaan`. In this column, I have data json like this ://

I update my question, this is dd not showing array on relational table user and alat. How? I need declare again in my controller? I update again, now I can show the data json. How can I parse it?

```
    Pemeliharaan {#274 ▼
  #table: "pemeliharaan"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 42
    "user_id" => 2
    "alat_id" => 1
    "pertanyaan" => array:8 [▼
      "question1" => "Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel"
      "answer1" => "false"
      "question2" => "Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan"
      "answer2" => "false"
      "question3" => "Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer)"
      "answer3" => "false"
      "question4" => "Fix and squish bugs"
      "answer4" => "false"
    ]
    "catatan" => "22-11-1996"
    "status" => "Harian"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2019-03-28 15:41:44"
    "updated_at" => "2019-03-28 15:41:44"
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
```

This data is question and answer. And I have a view like this. I have a function show and `showQuestion`.

And view like this

```
//View // no problem on here

<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama Alat</th>
                <th>Waktu</th>
                <th>User Input</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
              </tr>
              @php
              $no=0;
              @endphp

              @foreach ($pemeliharaan as $i)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$no }} </td>
                <td>{{ $i->alat->nama_alat}}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->status}}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->user->name}}</td>
                <td> <a href="/user/show/question/{{ $i->id }}" > <span class="label label-primary">Lihat Data</span> </a></td>//in here redirect to showQuestion
                <td>{{ $i->created_at}}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody></table>
</div>
```

`viewQuestion` (if I click the button on the table will view this data)

```
              @if( !is_null($pemeliharaan) )
             <p> Laporan : {{ $pemeliharaan->status }} </p> 
             <p> Tanggal : {{ $pemeliharaan->created_at }} </p> 
             <p> Jenis Alat   : {{ $pemeliharaan->alat->nama_alat }} </p> 
             <p> User    : {{ $pemeliharaan->user->name }} </p>  
             <p> pertanyaan : {{ $pemeliharaan['question1'] }} </p>// now showing anything 
             @endif 

                 @foreach(json_decode($pemeliharaan, true) as $value)
                 pertanyaan : {{ $value->pertanyaan['question1'] }}   
                 @endforeach //corect me at here 




//this is I want to decode this json but i dont
```

know what i do haha :(

this view (without question and answer) is don't have an error.

this is my controller :

```
public function show()
{
    $pemeliharaan = Pemeliharaan::with(['user','alat'])->get();
    return view('users.view',['pemeliharaan' => $pemeliharaan]);
}
 public function showQuestion($id)
{

     $pemeliharaan = Pemeliharaan::find($id);
     $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan = json_decode($pemeliharaan->pertanyaan,true);
     return view('users.view_question',compact('pemeliharaan'));
}
```

Having error like this

> Undefined index: alat (View: /var/www/html/new/resources/views/users/view_question.blade.php)

I don't know how to decode and how to view in blade

Comment: but i want to use it , i want to show my json data on colomn "pertanyaan' ,you can see at treadh

Comment: Pemeliharaan is table , pertanyaan is colomn in Pemeliharaan Table's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the specific column, not the whole object, try:

```
public function showQuestion($id)
{
    $pemeliharaan = Pemeliharaan::find($id);
    $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan = json_decode($pemeliharaan->pertanyaan,true);

    return view('users.view_question',compact('pemeliharaan'));
}
```

And check in the **viewQuestion** if `$pemeliharaan` is null or not :

```
@if( !is_null($pemeliharaan) )
    <p> Laporan : {{$pemeliharaan['status']}} </p> 
    <p> Tanggal : {{ $pemeliharaan['created_at'] }} </p> 
    <p> Jenis Alat   : {{ $pemeliharaan->alat->nama_alat }} </p> 
    <p> User    : {{ $pemeliharaan->user->name}} </p>  
    <p> pertanyaan : {{ $pemeliharaan['question1'] }} </p>
@endif
```

To parse all the Questions/Answers try :

```
@foreach($pemeliharaan->pertanyaan as $key => $value)
    pertanyaan : {{ $key . ' - ' . $value}}   
@endforeach
```

Play with this as you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the json mutator to cast the field in a json directly :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

```
 protected $casts = [
        'pertanyaan' => 'json',
    ];
```

Then if you want to display it, I advice you this following :

create a blade file `components/json.blade.php` :

```
@if (!is_string($value))
    @foreach($value as $key => $value)
        <span class="ml-3"><strong>{{ ucfirst($key) }}</strong> : @include('components.json')</span>
    @endforeach
@else
    {{ $value }}
@endif
```

Then in your main file :

`@include('components.json', ['value' => $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan])`

(I have no idea of what `pemeliharaan` AND `pertanyaan` means, so maybe it's mess up, but you should pass your json converted to array as a value

The result will be a recursive list of all your json data presented that way :

```
Question1 : Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel
Answer1 : false
Question2 : Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan
Answer2 : false
```

Comment: if i used json mutator i dont need a encode/decode this ?

Comment: with a mutator, when you are doing $object->your_json_field, it will be cast to json directly without needing to decode it